# Device grouping using k-means to create clusters with overlapping neiborhoods

Tags: clustering, matlab, k-means

I want to use k-means to group (cluster) my devices into overlapping regions. For example I randomly generate the locations of my node devices on an $XY$ plane such as $n_1$ at location $(x_1,y_1)$, $n_2$ at $(x_2,y_2)$ until $n_M$ at $(x_M,y_M)$. Each node has coverage radius R. I want to create the groups (clusters) using k-means in such a way that all the members in a group (cluster) are overlapping each other, meaning $d(n_1,n_2)\le 2R$. Any suggestion about how I can modify k-means to work in my scenario?

Comment: Why not generate device locations that achieve your goals directly, rather than generate random locations & then try to find some way to regroup them?

Answer (score 0):

Why k-means?

It's easy to see that for too small R there usually won't be a solution for small k.

That requirement clearly calls for hierarchical clustering instead. It LEADER clustering, and a few others.

Comment: I am considering both of them